# how to increase the limits of permissions requested per application - Azure AD signInAudience

Tags: azure, graph, permissions

I am currently developing an app that allows different operations with Microsoft SharePoint, I am using Microsoft Graph and I have registered the App in Azure AD, and it works fine.
But my wish is that the App is public and thousands of people can use it, using their Microsoft account.

But reading the documentation of Microsoft Graph I find an article that says that it has Limits of permissions requested by application.

I am currently developing an app that allows different operations with Microsoft SharePoint, I am using Microsoft Graph and I have registered the App in Azure AD, and it works fine.
But my wish is that the App is public and thousands of people can use it, using their Microsoft account.
But reading the documentation of Microsoft Graph I find an article that says that it has Limits of permissions requested by application

[Limits on requested permissions per app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1oDMF.png)

The limit indicated by the documentation is a maximum of 400 for a signInAudience= AzureADMultipleOrgs but I want and aspire to have more users, perhaps thousands of users. What do you recommend I do in this case? I want thousands of users to access the app with their Microsoft account and be able to do different activities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those limits are the number of permissions your app registration can have in the API permissions tab.
Not the number of users.
The number of users is not limited.

Comment: But when accessing the application, the first step that the user performs is to log in. Is logging in the same as the permissions requested by the application?  I am confused, every time a user accesses the application and logs in with his Microsoft user, the application asks for access permissions, these access permissions are not the same as in the image?

Comment: In the app when a user logs in, the app requests permission to access API Graph and performs the desired query, this process has to do with "Limits on requested permissions per app"???    For more information  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/permissions-reference

Comment: When a user logs in and the app asks for permissions that the user has not consented to, yeah they have to approve those permissions. But that is not for the 400 limit. It's just that your app can't ask for hundreds and hundreds of permissions at once from one user.